# Blynk notification with ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino-esp8266, arduino-ultra-sonic, esp8266wifi, blynk

This is my code which actually send blynk notification when distance is greater than 150. but its output is very weird. It again and again run setup function instead of only once. The esp8266 device goes online and offline and then again online due to this code. Can you tell me that why this runs setup function again and again and why it prints stack.......<< in output instead of serial.print() function.I don't know why? I am new to Blynk.

```
int trigPin = D4;
int echoPin = D5;
int led=D6;
#define BLYNK_PRINT Serial

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp8266.h>
#include <SPI.h>
char ssid[]="EVO-Charji-0A7E";
char pass[]="Kv4hFDEA";

int count=0;


// You should get Auth Token in the Blynk App.
// Go to the Project Settings (nut icon).
char auth[] = "1CfQ53wXPctk_gnrk_-ItbTWSgycPHq5";

BlynkTimer timer;

void notifyUptime(){

  long uptime = millis() / 60000L;
  //millis() is a fuction which returns the number of seconds the time has elapsed after the start of the device
  Serial.println("Running for 5 times");
  long duration, distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  duration=pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance =(duration/2)/29.1;
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println("CM");
  delay(10);

 if((distance<=150)) 
  {digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  Serial.println("enter");
    count=0;   unsigned long startTime=millis();
      unsigned long endTime=startTime;
      while((endTime-startTime) <=60000){
        if (distance>150){
          Blynk.notify("  Danger  \nGerms Alert!!!");
           Serial.println("leave");
          digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
          delay(1000);
          digitalWrite(led,LOW);
          delay(1000);
          digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
          count=count+1;
          break;
          }
        endTime=millis();
        }
        if (count==0){
          Blynk.notify("Successfully Cleaned the Hands.");
           Serial.println("success");
          digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
          }        
}
   else if(distance>150)
 {
  Serial.println("No man");  
   }
  //Blynk.notify(String("Running for ") + uptime + " minutes.");
  //   only one notification per 15 seconds is allowed. 
}
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
  delay(1000);
  // This mode allows NodeMCU to connect any WiFi directly.
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);        
  // Connect NodeMCU to your WiFi.
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  Serial.print("\n\n");
  Serial.print("Try to connect to WiFi. Please wait! ");
  Serial.print("\n\n");
  // Halt the code until connected to WiFi.
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print("*");
  }

  // If connection is successful, turn control led(if used) on and write WiFi SSID to serial monitor along with assigned IPAddress.
  Serial.print("\n\n");
  Serial.print("-------------------------------------");
  Serial.print("\n\n");
  Serial.print("Connection is successful!");
  Serial.print("\n\n");
  Serial.print("Connected WiFi SSID : ");
  Serial.print(ssid);
  Serial.print("\n\n");
  Serial.println("Connected IPAddress : ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("\n\n"); 
Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);

Serial.println("Device statred");
//Blynk.notify("Device started");
   // Setup a function to be called every minute
  timer.setInterval(10000L,notifyUptime);
  }

void loop(){
  Blynk.run();
    timer.run();
    }
```

The output of the code is shown below:

```
Try to connect to WiFi. Please wait! 

**********

-------------------------------------

Connection is successful!

Connected WiFi SSID : EVO-Charji-0A7E

Connected IPAddress : 
192.168.1.108


[6243] Connecting to EVO-Charji-0A7E
[6283] Connected to WiFi
[6310] IP: 192.168.1.108
[6337] 
    ___  __          __
   / _ )/ /_ _____  / /__
  / _  / / // / _ \/  '_/
 /____/_/\_, /_//_/_/\_\
        /___/ v0.6.1 on NodeMCU

[6492] Connecting to blynk-cloud.com:80
[7572] Ready (ping: 482ms).
Device statred
Running for 5 times
0CM
enter

Soft WDT reset

>>>stack>>>

ctx: cont
sp: 3ffffd40 end: 3fffffc0 offset: 01b0
3ffffef0:  00000000 00000000 00418937 00000000  
3fffff00:  402039e8 3ffeec9c 40100259 4bc6a7f0  
3fffff10:  00000000 3ffeec9c 3ffe886e 40203cc9  
3fffff20:  0056faef 00000005 3ffeec9c 40203d90  
3fffff30:  3ffee9c8 00000000 3ffeec9c 00000000  
3fffff40:  000044f1 3ffeec0c 3ffeec9c 402010c2  
3fffff50:  3ffee9c8 00000000 3ffee9c8 4020394c  
3fffff60:  00001dd7 00002710 000044e7 00000000  
3fffff70:  00000001 00000002 3ffeec9c 40202085  
3fffff80:  00000000 00000000 00000001 3ffeedc8  
3fffff90:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeed88 402020c1  
3fffffa0:  3fffdad0 00000000 3ffeed88 40204668  
3fffffb0:  feefeffe feefeffe 3ffe8528 40100cad  
<<<stack<<<
H!⸮ԅp⸮D⸮⸮⸮

Try to connect to WiFi. Please wait! 

**********

-------------------------------------

Connection is successful!

Connected WiFi SSID : EVO-Charji-0A7E

Connected IPAddress : 
192.168.1.108


[6244] Connecting to EVO-Charji-0A7E
[6284] Connected to WiFi
[6311] IP: 192.168.1.108
[6338] 
    ___  __          __
   / _ )/ /_ _____  / /__
  / _  / / // / _ \/  '_/
 /____/_/\_, /_//_/_/\_\
        /___/ v0.6.1 on NodeMCU

[6494] Connecting to blynk-cloud.com:80
[7381] Ready (ping: 478ms).
Device statred
```

.......it continues printing this again and again. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I now I am a bit late but i hope you still read this.

Your problem is very simple you try to connect to the WiFi to many times.
The setup function should look like this:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);


  Blynk.begin(auth, ssid, pass);

  Serial.println("Device statred");
  //Blynk.notify("Device started");
  // Setup a function to be called every minute
  timer.setInterval(10000L, notifyUptime);
}
```